# Waiting for async call in Angular2+

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, frontend

I've got method:

```
  prepareCalendarDaysToAdd() {
    this.getDaysToAdd();        //first line
    this.dataSaved.emit(this.daysToAdd); //second line
  }
```

And method getDaysToAdd() is an async call:

```
getDaysToAdd() {
    this.daysService.getDaysInSpecificYearWith(this.toDate.year).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.getCalendarDaysFrom(data);
      },
      error => { console.error(error); },
      () => {
        this.getCalendarDaysBetween();
      }
    )
  }
```

The problem is that data emits before its prepared.
How can I w8 to be sure if async call from first line is finished?

So the exact code I try to get is:

```
  prepareCalendarDaysToAdd() {
    if getDaysToAdd is finished then emit list of days
  }
```

I was trying to deal with promises to solve this problem, but seems like I do not understand how exactly it should work.

```
prepareCalendarDaysToAdd() {
     const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.getDaysToAdd();        //first line
      resolve();
      })
      .then(
      () => {
        this.dataSaved.emit(this.daysToAdd); //second line
        }
      );
    });
```

Comment: add `this.dataSaved.emit(this.daysToAdd);` inside subscribe function below `this.getCalendarDaysFrom(data);` line. Because as its async call so that data emit can be done inside its subscription

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code to resolve your issue :

add `this.dataSaved.emit(this.daysToAdd);` inside subscribe function below `this.getCalendarDaysFrom(data);` as its async call so that data emit can be done inside its subscription

```
prepareCalendarDaysToAdd() {
    this.getDaysToAdd();        //first line
    // removed second line
  }

getDaysToAdd() {
    this.daysService.getDaysInSpecificYearWith(this.toDate.year).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.getCalendarDaysFrom(data);
        this.dataSaved.emit(this.daysToAdd); // Added in success block of subscription
      },
      error => { console.error(error); },
      () => {
        this.getCalendarDaysBetween();
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, it helped out as you mentioned in comment. Thanks :)